# How to add extra text field in Civicrm Contribution page?

Tags: drupal, civicontribute

I want to add text field in Civicrm Contribution Setting Page (CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionPage_Settings). Please any one help me

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what you want to achhieve and why you want to achieve it? That way it is easier to help you.

Did you look into custom fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom field from civicrm UI and add that field to your contribution page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need field associated with contribution page or contribution?

**For contribution**:

You can create custom group extending contribution and then add custom field in it and then include the custom field in a profile.

**For Contribution page:**

Currently CiviCRM doesn't allow to create custom field to extend contribution page. [JMA Consulting](http://jmaconsulting.biz/home) have developed an [extension](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.contributionpagecustomfield) to have custom field extend contribution page. This extension is not yet released in civicrm.org but they are hoping it to release it soon. You can try by downloading and installing manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you can clarify the goal you want to achieve then it would be better to explain but i believe you can add text field in contribution settings page itself using [hook_civicrm_buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) and putting an if condition for variable `$formName` to be equal to 'CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionPage_Settings' alongwith with form_id which will be the contribution page id.

If your question was to add custom field in contribution page, you can achieve that by creating a custom field, then create a new profile and include custom field in that profile and in the end include the created profile in contribution page settings in 'Profiles' tab.